# Salesforce Apex Get string value of Field api name

Tags: apex

Query:

```
quoteInstance = [SELECT ID, SBQQ__QuoteProcessId__c,SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Tracker_Sold__c, Name, OwnerId 
FROM SBQQ__Quote__c 
WHERE ID =: quoteId ];
```

I am trying to convert object name and field name into its string value.
I tried

```
String myobjectstring = String.valueOf(quoteInstance.getSObjectType());
```

I get string value of the object.
How to get a string value of API name of the field "Tracker_Sold__c"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of the field from this instance, access it via the field path:

```
String trackerSold = quoteInstance.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Tracker_Sold__c;
```

If the field is not a textual type, convert it with `String.valueOf()`.

Comment: I need API name of the field Tracker_Sold__c

Comment: @SFDC I'm confused. The API name *is* Tracker_Sold__c. Can you step back and provide more context?

Comment: I need to pass object name and field API name to the method.   Method ( string object, string fieldapiname)